# Does POSIX have any equivilent of `DisconnectEx`?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, posix

[DisconnectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737757(v=vs.85).aspx), provided by the Windows API, allows you to disconnect a socket and reuse it for a new socket-based connection. this way one can build socket-pools to increase performance.

Does POSIX have any equivalent of it? from the look of it, it doesn't have one. you are forced to close the socket (with `closesocket` or `close`) and ask for a new one whenever you need so. maybe creating a socket in UNIX OS's is so cheap it isn't worth implementing this kind of a function, but I could not prove it.

Comment: Can you name some free software using `DisconnectEx`? Perhaps you could run similar benchmarks on  Windows & on Linux, and measure the difference. BTW, the POSIX specification (or the C11, or C++14 one) don't speak of -so in theory don't even care about- performance

Comment: BTW, `closesocket` does not seem to be a POSIX function. Any reference mentionning that as POSIX?

Comment: AFAIU, POSIX does *not have* any equivalent of `DisconnectEx`.

Comment: I know libuv and ngnix use `DisconnectEx`, although, I don't remember if they use it to pool the sockets. and you're right, `closesocket` is a qindows specific function.

Comment: `closesocket` is a windows thing.  Outside of Windows, creating a socket is really cheap so there is no way to disconnect and reuse a socket that I know of.

Comment: So you can benchmark `ngnix` on Linux and on Windows (on the *same* hardware) -with a similar load- and draw your conclusions regarding performance.

Comment: I didn't say that the Windows version runs faster than the Linux one, I said that on Windows, pooling the sockets using `DisconnectEx` brings better performance than not pooling them, on Windows.

Comment: You won't find any *proof* (that is a very strong word), but I tend to believe that Linux is well enough designed so that indeed it isn't worth implementing this kind of function on it. But the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study it and patch it to add such a feature. My intuition is that it is not worth the effort (you could need at least a year of work to try), but feel free to experiment.

Comment: You can `connect` "connectionless protocol sockets (Datagram sockets)" multiple time (it will disconnect the socket then connect it to an other). You can not do it with stream sockets. see `man 2 connect`.

Comment: `DisconnectEx` is an extension to Winsock2. It does not exist on non-Windows platforms, and there is no cross-platform equivalent.

Comment: FYI, `closesocket` dispatches to the socket provider's `WSPCloseSocket` function. It typically makes at least one `NtClose` system call. For example, socket handles from the Winsock provider in mswsock.dll are kernel handles for the AFD device, but they're also associated with information in a user-mode socket table, such as the configuration for `SO_LINGER` mode. If lingering is enabled, Winsock has to make repeated IOCTL syscalls to poll for pending sends until the linger timeout, when it makes a final IOCTL to abort the connection, and then closes the handle via `NtClose`.